# How to Enable Box2D debugDraw in Lua?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, lua, box2d, cocos2d-x

I'm tring to open box2d debugDraw in Lua. As I know in Cpp, we need to override CCLayer:draw() function. But in Lua, I can't get the override work done. Did you guys have idea about it?

Comment: which Box2D binding are you using?

Comment: Hi Tiago, I'm using Tolua++. Actually, I've found a way to get it done. I implement a class in C++ which override the draw method then add it into the layer, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I implement a class derived from CCNode in C++ which override the draw method then binding with Lua.
Whenever you add it into, it works!